# Get closest (but higher) number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a number say 165

I have an array with numbers in it. Like this:

[2, 42, 82, 122, 162, 202, 242, 282, 322, 362]

I want that the number I've got changes to the nearest, but higher number of the array.

For example I get 165 it should go tot 202

javascript arrays

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: What did you try till now? Just a regular loop and check if the nr is bigger than the current item at the index should work (as it seems to be an ordered list) (any reason why all the differences are +40?)

Comment: If the numbers are sorted (as they are here), you can use binary search to find the answer in O(log n) time, instead of O(n) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using `Array.forEach()`:

```js
const number = 165;
const candidates = [2, 42, 82, 122, 162, 202, 242, 282, 322, 362];

//looking for the lowest valid candidate, so start at infinity and work down
let bestCandidate = Infinity;

//only consider numbers higher than the target
const higherCandidates = candidates.filter(candidate => candidate > number);

//loop through those numbers and check whether any of them are better than
//our best candidate so far
higherCandidates.forEach(candidate => {
    if (candidate < bestCandidate) bestCandidate = candidate;
});

console.log(bestCandidate); //the answer, or Infinity if no valid answers exist
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Any way to have a custom message instead of Infinity displayed.

Comment: You'll need to do an extra `if (bestCandidate === Infinity) {` clause at the end to catch that case and display something different.

Comment: I had to set it to -1 which was the value. it was undefined because it looked for that number in the array which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need sort array after a insert like this:

```
let list = [10, 20, 50];
let elementToInsert = 40;
list.push(elementToInsert);
list.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
```

Return must be [10, 20, 40, 50]

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by sorting the array and the iterating over it to find the first value satisfying your condition:

```js
const getFirst = (arr, predicate) => {
  for (const val of arr) {
    if (predicate(val)) return val;
  }
  return undefined;
}

const x = getFirst([2, 42, 82, 122, 162, 202, 242, 282, 322, 362].sort(), x => x > 165);

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

For you specific example:

```
var array = [2, 42, 82, 122, 162, 202, 242, 282, 322, 362];
var found = array.find(function(element) {return element > 165;});
```

When you log **found** you will always get 202.

This will always return the first element greater than your number,
which is logically closest and higher