# Get closest number of an array , but store the closest inside proxy array until no target number left (negative target number accepted)

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, numbers

the same as [Get closest (but higher) number in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54554384/get-closest-but-higher-number-in-an-array) answer
but the result is array , and would stop iterating when the target number is zero

example of my undone javascript script

```js
const counts = [4, 9, 15, 6, 2];
var goal = 122;
var proxyArray = [];

function closest(arr, goal){
  if (goal >= 0) {
    return arr.reduce(function(done,curr){
      if(Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(done - goal)){
        goal = goal - curr;
        proxyArray.push(curr);
      }

      return proxyArray;
    }, []);
  } else {
    return proxyArray;
  }
}
const output = closest(counts, goal);

console.log(proxyArray);
```

Expected result :

```
[4,9, ...] //until the total worth equal or above (but closest) to 122 (goal/left)
```

but got unexpected result.

this is just an example, in real development i was using the same great numbers so callstack problems is not really a big problem.

NOTE : help me sensei

Comment: what will be the **complete** expected result for the example array and goal you have mentioned

Comment: you have given three dots (...) as part of the array, i was just wondering what will come in place of them for  `counts = [4, 9, 15, 6, 2];` and `goal = 122;`

Comment: @TharunK that's just example,  in real life development i was using the same great numbers